# Passing Boolean Value Into Directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to toggle the visibility of an element rendered by a directive using `<div ngHide="readOnly">`.  The value or `readOnly` is passed in via a directive.

```
angular.module('CrossReference')
    .directive('singleViewCard', [function() {
        return {
            restrict:'AE',
            templateUrl: '/CrossReference-portlet/js/templates/SingleViewCard.html',
            replace:true,
            scope: {
                readOnly:'@'

            },
            link: {
                pre:function(scope, tElement, tAttrs) {}, 
                post:function(scope, tElement, tAttrs) {};
                }
            }
        };
    }]);
```

This seems to work in the following cases:

```
<!-- element rendered in single-view-card is hidden -->
<div single-view-card read-only="{{true}}"/>

<!-- element rendered in single-view-card is shown -->
<div single-view-card read-only="{{false}}"/>
```

However, if I invert the boolean expression `<div ngHide="!readOnly">` The following usage of the directive does not hide the dive as expected:

```
<!-- element is rendered when it should be hidden -->
<div single-view-card read-only="{{false}}"/>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 125, accepted):

what you are doing wrong is

```
readOnly:'@'
```

this means readOnly will be a string, to make it a js variable try

```
readOnly:'='
```

then

```
<div single-view-card read-only="{{false}}"/>
```

should be

```
<div single-view-card read-only="true"/>
```

you need to show more code, this can be part of the error but I think there is more

Comment: Thank you.  So if @ means that my readOnly property becomes a string, how would the ngHide expression be evaluated?

Comment: @timmy i dont know why it works in your case, that's why I asked for more code

Comment: @timmy That is the golden question. `readOnly` is a variable of type string, and it should be evaluated in a template only when surrounded by double curly braces e.g. `ngHide="{{readOnly}}"` ... but why is it still being evaluated when the template is `ngHide="readOnly"`? I find it very strange.

Comment: @bto.rdz I created the following fiddle that illustrates the problem here [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/timeapen/x5bag0m5/10/).  Notice that the <div> is hidden when the user types true.  It is displayed if the user types false. <br/> Notice that if in invert the logic so that the div in the template operates on ng-hide="!readOnly", then typing in false in the input field does not hide the <div>.  Strange.

Comment: But if you try to change value of readOnly in directive it throws Non-Assignable Expression Error https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$compile/nonassign

Comment: Not using the angular expression syntax when assigning the attribute worked for me, thank you so much for being clear and concise and spot on

Answer (score 10):

Currently it does not work because as [bto.rdz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2979430/bto-rdz) mentionned in his answer, `@` will read the raw value of the attribute, this is why you needed to interpolate your boolean value.
In the following example, you can switch the value of `readOnly` at the directive's scope level through a controller holding the model `ctrlReadOnly`.

What I suggest instead is to use a scope variable to make it dynamic with `=`.

**How to use your directive**

```
<div single-view-card read-only="ctrlReadOnly"></div>
```

---

### The directive looks like this

```
angular.module('CrossReference', [])
    .directive('singleViewCard', [function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        template: '<div ng-hide="readOnly">Hidden when readOnly is true</div>',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            readOnly: '='
        }
    };
}])
```

### Here is a fake controller to prepare the data for the view

```
.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.ctrlReadOnly = false;
});
```

---

**I made a js fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/axelduch/y43q93zk/4/)**

Answer (score 5):

In the (post 1.5) component world, this can be achieved using '<' to pass the boolean along as a one-time binding.

[Angular Components Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component)

> Inputs should be using < and @ bindings. The < symbol denotes one-way bindings which are available since 1.5. The difference to = is that the bound properties in the component scope are not watched, which means if you assign a new value to the property in the component scope, it will not update the parent scope.

Answer (score 4):

Your directive is fine (except that there shouldn't be a semicolon after `post:function(scope, tElement, tAttrs) {}`).

Directive usage:

```
<div single-view-card read-only="true"></div>
```

In SingleViewCard.html:

```
<div ng-hide="!{{readOnly}}">Lorem ipsum</div>
```

Note that the exclamation mark comes before the curly braces.

**Explanation**

```
scope: {
    readOnly:'@'
},
```

means that `readOnly` becomes a variable that holds a string value specified by the `read-only` attribute. We can then use our `readOnly` variable in the template by surrounding it with double curly braces.

I have also made a jsFiddle for it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cLk4pwo1/).

Comment: Thanks. Also worth noting that @ and = really aren't the same and should not be used interchangeably so this solution is more correct for a setting to configure a directive.